# How to make uppercase records in purescript?

Tags: record, uppercase, purescript

I have an API that forces me to return a JSON in the form of

```json
{ Field1: "something"
, Field2: 12 }
```

However, I have failed to model this in Purescript so far.

I understand that the purescript grammar sees the upper case field names and thinks it is the type of a field without a field name. So I it is not straight forward to just encode a function like

```
test :: Number -> { Field1 :: String, Field2 :: Number }
```

Without resorting to using external javascript functions to change the object into something else, is it at all possible to construct a record with upper case field names in purescript? And if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely! PureScript allows *any* field names, not just "valid identifier" ones. You just have to double-quote them if they're weird:

```
x :: { "Field1" :: String, "Field2" :: String, "" :: String }
x = { "Field1": "foo", "Field2": "bar", "": "yum" }

y :: String
y = x.""
```

Basically same deal as in JavaScript.